# Integral with Legendre polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, special-functions, definite-integrals

What is $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} P_l(\cos(\theta))P_{l'}(\cos(\theta)) \sin(\theta) d\theta$$ in general?
 Of course, $P_l$ is the l-th Legendre polynomial.
Obvisiouly it is for even/even and odd/odd $$\frac{1}{2n+1} \delta_{nm}$$ and otherwise?

Comment: See this [excellent answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/452800/73025).

Comment: right, truly amazing

Comment: Change $x=\cos(\theta)$ and look in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tough Legendre Integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452727/tough-legendre-integral)